# Update power dns from EPEL repo

Tags: centos, powerdns, epel

I'm using EPEL repo on Centos 6. If I start update for power dns with mysql backend - so please - must I update mysql schema manually, or YUM will do this self?

Thank youů

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must update the schema yourself.

Check the PowerDNS website for information on [upgrades](http://doc.powerdns.com/html/upgrades.html). Some changes are backward compatible and don't require you to update the schema every time.